# My ZTE WCDMA modem doesn't work because of architecture incompatibility

Tags: 16.04

My system is ubuntu 16.04.3 , i try to install a network usb modem

#### $uname -a

4.10.0-33-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 14:07:24 UTC 2017
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
..................start install.................
*** Check for root.../usr/lib/libqt-mt.so.3 /usr/lib/libqt-mt.so.3.3.8 /usr/lib/libqt-mt.so.3.3 /usr/lib/libqt-mt.so
check QT3 Runtime Library successfully.
check wvdial successfully.
ok...
/PCCFG/Description.xml,/tmp/two_phase_temp/Description.xml
Device is open : (0x19d2, 0x154)
Can not obtain size of file: /PCCFG/Description.xml
stage 2
Stage 3
Etisalat_USB_Modem/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/backup/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Language/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/bin/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/usr/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/log/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/driver/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/ContactsBackup/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/pppd/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/etc/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/sound/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/usr/share/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/usr/lib/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/ContactsBackup/SIM/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/ContactsBackup/PC/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/network/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/base/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/phonebook/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/loginMask/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/pics/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/sms/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/dataConnect/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/etc/ppp/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/usr/share/pixmaps/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/usr/share/applications/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/etc/ppp/peers/
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Etisalat_USB_Modem
Etisalat_USB_Modem/uninstall.sh
Etisalat_USB_Modem/update
Etisalat_USB_Modem/UpdateCfg.ini
Etisalat_USB_Modem/launch-gui.sh
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/.version.txt
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/version.txt
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/extendTotalRecord.conf
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/apnmatchflag.conf
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/get_system_info.sh
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/launchFirefox.sh
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/common-config.xml
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/modem_types.xml
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/sms.xml
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/.common-config.xml.swp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/defaultRecord.conf
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/totalRecord.conf
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/run_evince.sh
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/networkrc.xml
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/autostart.sh
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/callrecord.xml
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/historyRecord.xml
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/aplay.sh
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/ussdRecord.xml
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/contact.xml
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/config
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Language/Italian.qm
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Language/Simplified_Chinese.qm
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Language/Traditional_Chinese.qm
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Language/English.qm
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Language/Spanish.qm
Etisalat_USB_Modem/bin/9-cdrom.rules
Etisalat_USB_Modem/bin/Etisalat_USB_Modem
Etisalat_USB_Modem/driver/nm.pp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/driver/driver_uninstall.sh
Etisalat_USB_Modem/driver/disselfirefox.pp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/driver/driver_install.run
Etisalat_USB_Modem/driver/se
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/startingWindow.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/smsBar434x29.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/aboutWindow.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/close_butt.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/smsBar434x29mask.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icon.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/smsBar434x29.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/aboutWindow.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/minimize_butt.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/pppd/ip-down.local
Etisalat_USB_Modem/pppd/get_route_info
Etisalat_USB_Modem/pppd/ip-up.local
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/etc/resolv.conf
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/etc/wvdial.conf
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/sound/sms.wav
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/sound/connect.wav
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/sound/disconnect.wav
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/sound/call.wav
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/help.html
Etisalat_USB_Modem/usr/lib/libmd5.so
Etisalat_USB_Modem/usr/lib/libagent.so
Etisalat_USB_Modem/usr/lib/libtinyxml.so
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/help3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/set3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/help1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/preparidpackages3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/AliceMobile1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/stk0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/phonebook1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/set1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/swUpdate0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/set2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/swUpdate1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/swUpdate2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/sms1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/swUpdate3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/AliceMobile0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/preparidpackages2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/sms2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/preparidpackages0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/sms0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/homeicon3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/mobile_icon.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/sms3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/logoOnFram.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/phonebook2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/set0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/AliceMobile2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/phonebook3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/help2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/stk3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/homeicon2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/stk2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/help0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/homeicon1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/phonebook0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/AliceMobile3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/homeicon0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/stk1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/icons/preparidpackages1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/network/StateImageList0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/network/FindNetImage1.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/network/select.gif
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/network/StateImageList3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/network/search.gif
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/network/StateImageList1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/network/StateImageList2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/msg_query.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/msg_information.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/connstatisdlgbar.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/MsgBoxImage.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/part5MessageBox.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/part1MessageBOX234x121.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/progress.gif
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/sms_animation.gif
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/close1.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/NewMsgBackImage.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/connstatisdlgbg.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/MsgBoxBack.BMP
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/barMessageBOX238x23.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/NewMsgSMSButton.PNG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/messagebox_btn45x19.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/close.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/contact_animation.gif
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/messageBox/msg_warning.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_TrayMain6.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/sim_off.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_TrayMain0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_NewSms.gif
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/modem_on.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/data1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ILIcon5.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_IncomingCall2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/uninsert.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_NewSms0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/sim_on.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/DataAniImageList0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ILIcon3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/StateImageList0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ILIcon0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImImage_IncomingCall.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/modem_off.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_MemFull0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_RSSILevel0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_power2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/DataStateImageList1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/DataStateImage.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_TrayMain9 .png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_power1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/data_disconnect.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_Internet3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/DataStateImageList0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_TrayMain2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_TrayMain8.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ILIcon2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_NewSms2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_RSSILevel2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/datastate1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_NewSms1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/StateImageList3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_MemFull1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/data0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_NewSms3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/DataAniImageList3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_MemFull2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/sim_cancel.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/data2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_power3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/nosimcard.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImImage_Close.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_RSSILevel5.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_Internet0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ILIcon4.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImImage_NewSms.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_IncomingCall3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/Call_IMbutton.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/datastate0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/StateImageList1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_power4.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_Internet1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_TrayMain5.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_RSSILevel4.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_Internet2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_TrayMain3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ILIcon6.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ILIcon1 .png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/StateImageList2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/DataAniImageList4.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_power0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/iconBackground.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_TrayMain4.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_TrayMain7.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/SMS_IMbutton.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/DataAniImageList1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_TrayMain1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_IncomingCall0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/DataAniImageList2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_RSSILevel3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_IncomingCall1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/Reject_IMbutton.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/component/ImageList_RSSILevel1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/base/top_copy.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/base/bottomBar.gif
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/base/baseBG.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/base/widgetstack.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/base/bottom_copy.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/base/CentreBG.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/base/configBackground.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/base/connectframe.JPG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/base/pixlabel.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/base/centre_copy.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/base/sms_widgetstack.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/base/centralBG626x317.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/phonebook/phonebookBarBackGround380x30.png1
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/phonebook/ILIcon3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/phonebook/ILIcon0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/phonebook/ILIcon2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/phonebook/phonebookBar425x30.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/phonebook/ILIcon4.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/phonebook/PhoneBook11 copy.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/phonebook/phonebookBarBackGround380x30.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/phonebook/centralBG626x317.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons12.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons9.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons0.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons10.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/checknumber.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons7mask.MID.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons6.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons11mask.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons13.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons12mask.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons14.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons7.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons11.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons7.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/button_apn_invalid.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons6.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons88.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/loginMaskButt52x22.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons6.MID.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons4.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons10.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons4.MID.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons12.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons159x37.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons7mask.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons10mask.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons50x23.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons57x23.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/button_apn_valid.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/button13.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons3.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons3.MID.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons7copy.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons61x21.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons9.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons77.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons8.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons7.MID.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons5.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons1.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons9mask.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons2.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons14.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons11.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons5.MID.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons8.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons13.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/buttons/buttons6.MID.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/Dial_9.PNG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/hangup.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/Dial_2.PNG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/Dial_3.PNG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/Dial_6.PNG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/volume.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/Dial_0.PNG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/Dial_7.PNG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/Dial_1.PNG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/Dial_4.PNG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/Dial_star.PNG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/Dial_5.PNG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/Dial_cancle.PNG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/micpic.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/dial_down.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/misscall.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/Dial_8.PNG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/hangup_down.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/Dial_#.PNG
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/dial.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/call/dial_connecting.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/loginMask/TopBar.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/loginMask/loginMaskButt52x22.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/loginMask/msg_information.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/loginMask/loginMaskBar259x25.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/loginMask/loginMask0.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/loginMask/loginMask2.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/loginMask/close.bmp
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/loginMask/loginMaskcentre259x25.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/loginMask/loginMask1.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/pics/ILIcon3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/pics/ILIcon0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/pics/ILIcon2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/pics/Button1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/pics/test.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/pics/ILIcon4.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/pics/Image6.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/pics/Image2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/pics/Image3.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/sms/BtLtoR.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/sms/BtRtoL.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/sms/Contenbak.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/sms/toplabel.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/sms/search.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/sms/button2.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/dataConnect/bar608x29copy.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/dataConnect/connecting.gif
Etisalat_USB_Modem/res/dataConnect/connected.gif
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/etc/ppp/resolv.conf
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/etc/ppp/options
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/sim_off.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/a_020_help
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/modem_on.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/sim_on.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/modem_off.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/data_disconnect.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/stk0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/image001.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/ImageList_NewSms1.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/swUpdate0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/data0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/a_024_help
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/AliceMobile0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/preparidpackages0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/sms0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/set0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/a_017_help
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/a_007_help
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/icon.jpg
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/help0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/phonebook0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/a_004_help
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/homeicon0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/help/index_files/call0.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/usr/share/pixmaps/Etisalat_USB_Modem.png
Etisalat_USB_Modem/usr/share/applications/Etisalat_USB_Modem.desktop
Etisalat_USB_Modem/Data/etc/ppp/peers/wvdial
ls: cannot access '/usr/share/applications/desktop.*.cache': No such file or directory
udevadm is exist!
******Begin to /opt/Etisalat_USB_Modem/driver
this is linux driver installtion
make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-33-generic/build M=/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.o
/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.c:21354:16: error: ‘usb_serial_probe’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  .probe      = usb_serial_probe,
                ^
/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.c:21355:16: error: ‘usb_serial_disconnect’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  .disconnect = usb_serial_disconnect,
                ^
/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.c: In function ‘onda_init’:
/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.c:21433:11: error: implicit declaration of function ‘usb_serial_register’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  retval = usb_serial_register(&onda_1port_device);
           ^
/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.c:21446:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘usb_serial_deregister’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  usb_serial_deregister(&onda_1port_device);
  ^
/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.c: In function ‘onda_instat_callback’:
/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.c:21510:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘dbg’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  dbg("%s", __func__);
  ^
/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.c:21548:3: error: called object ‘err’ is not a function or function pointer
   err("%s: error %d", __func__, status);
   ^
/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.c:21505:6: note: declared here
  int err;
      ^
In file included from ./include/linux/module.h:18:0,
                 from /tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.c:20880:
/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.c: In function ‘__check_debug’:
./include/linux/moduleparam.h:344:67: error: return from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  static inline type __always_unused *__check_##name(void) { return(p); }
                                                                   ^
./include/linux/moduleparam.h:396:35: note: in expansion of macro ‘__param_check’
 #define param_check_bool(name, p) __param_check(name, p, bool)
                                   ^
./include/linux/moduleparam.h:146:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘param_check_bool’
  param_check_##type(name, &(value));       \
  ^
./include/linux/moduleparam.h:126:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘module_param_named’
  module_param_named(name, name, type, perm)
  ^
/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.c:21598:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘module_param’
 module_param(debug, bool, S_IRUGO | S_IWUSR);
 ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:301: recipe for target '/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42/onda.o] Error 1
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.42] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic'
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
this  is customized kernel ,kernel version is: 4.10.0-33-generic
enter customize_driver_install function
cp: cannot stat 'onda.ko': No such file or directory
modprobe: FATAL: Module onda not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-33-generic
disselfirefox.pp driver_install.run driver_uninstall.sh nm.pp se End to /opt/Etisalat_USB_Modem/driver
install completed!!!
....After setup, you will find the Etisalat USB Modem in "Applications->Internet->Etisalat USB Modem". Click the Etisalat USB Modem and the application will run
press any key to continue.... 
Etisalat_USB_Modem: error while loading shared libraries: libqt-mt.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

usually the program work fine even with the code errors, with some bugs but it works, but now i got

#### error while loading shared libraries: libqt-mt.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

in the end when i search for the problem i understand that the binaries are 32bit and the system is 64bit and i need 32bit libraries like ia32-libs but when i try to install it

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch  
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

so anyone can help me!!!!

Comment: Do `sudo apt update`, then `sudo apt install -f` then go ahead and install!

Comment: same problemm nothing change

Comment: Did the `sudo apt install -f` go through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after digging i manage to make the modem software run

#### First for the problem

```
error while loading shared libraries: libqt-mt.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

I've checked the /usr/lib32/libqt* there was nothing so i tried

```
apt-get install libqt3-mt:i386
```

the libqt3-mt:i386 && /usr/lib32/libqt* packages installed successfully and resolved the error

#### For the code error problem

it is because the script check if the system is Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 version and consequently issues install_driver

```sh
if [ "Ubuntu 12.04" != "$(getU1204)" -a "Ubuntu 12.10" !=   "$(getU1210)" ];then
    if [ "Fedora release 17" != "$(getFc17)" -a "Fedora release 18" != "$(getFc18)" ];then
        install_driver
    fi
fi
```

so i make the return of the function getU1204 "Ubuntu 12.04", the code error disappeared when i tried to reinstall the modem.

Hope this will help anyone face the same problem